# GWT Layout: "take up the rest of the space."

Tags: gwt, layout, uibinder

My existing layout is a stack of two divs - g:layers in a LayoutPanel.  The top div should be as big as it needs to be to contain its contents.  The bottom div should take up the rest of the space on the screen, without causing scrollbars to appear.

The contents of the top div can change, so the size of the top div can change.

My current solution is a callback that's triggered whenever the contents of the top div change.  The containing LayoutPanel can then recalculate the size of the top div and explicitly set the `top` and `bottom` attributes of the second layer to take up the rest of the space.  Is there a better way?  Something like,

```
<g:LayoutPanel>
    <g:layer top="0px" height="whatever you need, baby">
        <c:SomeWidget/>
    </g:layer>
    <g:layer top="the bottom of the first layer" bottom="0px">
        <c:Anotherwidget/>
    </g:layer>
</g:LayoutPanel>
```

Comment: If you don't want scrollbars at all, then there's an easy solution: Use a FlowPanel with `overflow: hidden`. But I assume, you do want a scrollbar to appear, when the bottom panel overflows? I'd like to see a solution for that, too (I mean one that also works in strict mode). Not sure, if it's possible with CSS 2.1 at all (?)

Comment: Yeah, I do need the size for a ScrollPanel in the second layer.  Arrgh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be that there is not a better way.  Manual recalculation isn't so bad when you get used to it!

Answer (score 1):

What about using `DockLayoutPanel`?

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit='PX'>
  <north size="10" ui:field='northWidget'>
    <c:SomeWidget/>
  </north>
  <center>
    <c:Anotherwidget/>
  </center>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

Then the `center` will take up the rest of the space. If you want to resize the top, call 
`setWidgetSize(northWidget, newSize);` and the `center` widget will be recalculated.

Comment: But I still have to calculate the size of the `northWidget`, right?  I'm looking for a solution that will automatically flow when northWidget changes size.

Answer (score 0):

I think HeaderPanel is the standard Widget to do this. Maybe it was added after the question was asked. We missed it too and had our own version for a while.